# Write a difference equation which is the analog of the ODE $\dot{x}= ax$ and solve it

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Write a difference equation which is the analog of the ODE **$\dot{x}= ax$** and solve it.
So after dividing the interval [0,t] into subintervals with length $h=t/n$ we replace the derivative by the quotient so the ODE became a difference equation
$(x_{k+1}-x_k)/h = ax_k$ .

Now I am confused as to how to solve this. The clue that I have is to write $x_n$ in terms of $x_0$ and show $x_n$ tends to $e^{at}x_0$ as n is approaching infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
(x_{k+1} - x_k)/h = a x_k \implies x_{k+1} = \left(1 + ah\right)\,x_k 
$$
Now
$$
x_1 = (1+ah) x_0\\
x_2 = (1+ ah)\, x_1 = (1+ah)^2x_0 \\
\vdots\vdots\vdots \\
x_{n} = (1+ah)x_{n-1} = \cdots = (1+ah)^{n} x_0
$$
hence
$$
x_n = (1+ah)^n x_0 = \left( 1 + \frac{at}{n}\right)^n x_0
$$
now taking $n \to \infty$...